# Как вывести аватар в комментарий

Tags: php, mysql, sql, база-данных, комментарии

Подскажите пожалуйста в таком вопросе: Как мне вывести аватар пользователя в его комментарий?

Есть две таблицы, **topic2** и **users**.

Структура **users**: *id, login, name, pass, avatar.*

Структура **topic2**: *id, title, description, nameauthor, regdate.*

Связаны эти таблицы между собой по *name* в **users** и *nameauthor* в **topic2**

Данные из **topic2** выводятся с помощью функции:

```
//функция вывода страницы поста
function getPostsTopicTwo($post_id) {
    global $mysqli;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM topic2 WHERE id = ".$post_id;
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
    $postTopicTwoGet = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    return $postTopicTwoGet;
}



//выводятся данные сюда
$postGetAddTopicTwo = getPostsTopicTwo($post_id);

<div id="h1">
         <h1><?=$postGetAddTopicTwo['title']?></h1>
     </div>
      <div id="post_page">
          <div id="author_block">
                 <img src="<?=$postGetAddTopicTwo['img']?>" alt="">
              <a href="/profileuser?name=<?=$postGetAddTopicTwo['nameauthor']?>"><p id="name_author"><?=$postGetAddTopicTwo['nameauthor']?></p></a>
                  <p>Пользователь</p>
                  <p>Регистрация</p>
                  <p>Репутация</p>
          </div>
          <div id="author_post">
          <p id="dateadd">Дата добавления: <?=$postGetAddTopicTwo['regdate']?></p>
          <br>
          <hr>
          <br>
          <?=$postGetAddTopicTwo['description']?>
          </div>
      </div>
```

Функция выводит текст поста, автора и дату создания из таблицы **topic2**.
А как вывести аватар автора (пользователя) из другой таблицы с названием **users**, где лежит ссылка на аватар у каждого пользователя?

Как в зависимости от того, какое имя у автора, выводить именно его картинку из таблицы **users**?

Comment: Суть примерно понятна что ты хотел спросить, но того кода что ты скинул и как сформировал вопрос, недостаточно для того чтоб дать на него конкретный ответ в виде кода. Если словами, то при проектировании баз дынных, таблицы в основном связаны по какому то полю.Выбираешь из одной таблицы, данные и id, и в другой таблице под таким же id должен быть user

Comment: А если не по id а полю name допустим, тоже можно?

Comment: @Андрей Солуянов, как бы вы реализовали данный вопрос, можете свой вариант кода написать?

Comment: Ну я так понимаю что у тебя минимум две таблицы есть.  topic2 и users, Структура вопроса {Есть две таблицы, такая то и такая то. Их структуры.Указать по какому полю они связаны(в идеале), Знаю как выбрать из первой таблицы то то , но не пойму как выбрать связанные с ней значения в другой таблице, такие то и такие то } Примерно так.А по другому только на словах тебе ответят. Делай выборку нужную в первой, находи в ней нужное поле id. или name а потом ищи в другой что нужно. Можно запросить двумя запросами, А можно написать запрос который вернет результат проходя по двум таблицам. Вариантов lot

Comment: Это  если я все верно понял, могу и ошибаться в понимании.

Comment: @АндрейСолуянов, изменил вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я тебя правильно понял, то можно сделать так.

Сделав первый запрос к таблице topic2, в поле $postGetAddTopicTwo['nameauthor'] по идеи у тебя имя которое  ты хочешь найти в таблице user.

Далее пишешь второй запрос, которой обращается к таблице user и выбирает в ней строку в которой name= $postGetAddTopicTwo['nameauthor'].

Примерно так это может выглядеть.

```
//функция вывода страницы поста
function getPostsTopicTwo($post_id) {
    global $mysqli;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM topic2 WHERE id = ".$post_id;
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
    $postTopicTwoGet = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    return $postTopicTwoGet;
}
$postGetAddTopicTwo = getPostsTopicTwo($post_id);


/*
    Добавляем функцию которая обращается к таблице users
    и выбираем user.name=topic2.nameauthor
*/
function getPostsAvatar($post_name) {
    global $mysqli;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM  users WHERE name = ".$post_name;
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
    $postTopicTwoGet = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    return $postTopicTwoGet;
}

/*
    Вызываем функцию getPostsAvatar и в нее передаем значение
    nameauthor полученное в переменной из предыдущего запроса
*/

$postGetPostsAvatar=getPostsAvatar($postGetAddTopicTwo['nameauthor']);

/*
   В $postGetPostsAvatar['avatar'] должен быть выдан нужный аватар
*/

echo($postGetPostsAvatar['avatar']);
```

Comment: ошибка **Warning:** *mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in* в строчке  **$postTopicTwoGet = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);**

Comment: так я  $postTopicTwoGet не писал)), в общем , я тебе как это сделать написал,Убирай мой код, запускай, проверяй что работает что нет, проверь что возвращает $postGetAddTopicTwo['nameauthor'], то ли имя которое нужно выбрать в таблице user. Попробуй getPostsAvatar() вызвать уже с указанным именем которое есть в таблицах, например getPostsAvatar("Петя") что вернет.  Как можно вывести данные с разных таблиц, один вариант я тебе показал, запросами поочередно. А что там у тебя не идет, эт .я.хз. Тебе нужно разобраться в теме 'SQL-запрос на выборку из нескольких таблиц' с php и просто sql

Comment: В твоей функции, которую ты написал **getPostsAvatar($post_name)** указывает на строчку **$postTopicTwoGet = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)**.  Мой код весь работает.

Comment: Таблица users есть точно? в ней поле name есть точно? ты базу через что смотришь через phpMyAdmin? или на локальной машине обращаешься через консоль?

Comment: локальная машина OpenServer  с базой PhpMyAdmin. Таблица users есть точно и в ней поле name есть точно!)

Comment: Ну пройдись в myАdmine просто по sql .SELECT * FROM  users WHERE name = "нужное имя", вернет ли он нужную строку с нужны аватарам

Comment: Нашлась ошибка: вместо этого **$sql = "SELECT * FROM  users WHERE name = ".$post_name;** поставил это **$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = '$post_name'";**  и всё зафурычило) Спасибо друг! Ты мне очень помог.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111059/discussion-between---and-artisuc).